# Substitute for Visual FoxPro

Tags: database, visual-foxpro, procedural-programming

I would like to know if there's a substitute for Visual FoxPro. The last version is 9.0. With the language FoxPro 3.0 so, I was wondering of someone knows a language similar to FoxPro with a development environment similar to Visual FoxPro 9.0. I know there's dBase but I don't know if it's powerful enough like FoxPro and I also know xHarbour but I haven't tried it.

Comment: FWIW I googled for FoxPro (I have not looked at it in years) and found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vfoxpro/bb190225.aspx which has a note at top about an "awesome new MSFT-sanctioned replacement platform" that I've never heard about, YMMV :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hear Servoy is one of the platforms VFP developers are moving towards. And it's either free or inexpensive. Check out http://www.servoy.com/

Comment: I heard about it too, but I think it's SaaS, so it's not my preference.

Comment: Yes it's very much that model.

Answer (score 2):

Lianja App Builder has a high degree of compatibility with Visual FoxPro.
www.lianja.com

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there are is not a similar programing language to Visual FoxPro.  FoxPro was one and still is one of the best programming languages out there.  You can still use Version 9 with SP2 but there will be no 64 bit support in the last version.  It will run on all windows platforms in 32 bit just fine.  If you are looking to convert your current version of Visual FoxPro I found Servoy.

You can check these links about FoxPro conversion into Servoy.
http://www.servoy.com/content.jsp?t=1283&pageid=dlfoxpro

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rUsMMLbcqY

Comment: There is 64-bit support - it runs fine on 64-bit Windows. Is there a 64-bit version of the IDE and language itself? No, in common with 90% of the other development tools out there.

Answer (score 0):

First what do you mean by 'substitute for VFP'?  Are you just looking for a rapid application development tool?

I don't know about everyone else in the VFP world,  but I still develop using VFP 9 and my products run under all versions of Windows; however, I'm migrating most of my stuff to Visual Studio using C# and .NET.

You're not going to find anything that mimics VFP (at least not that I'm aware of)

Comment: I'm not talking about and IDE cuz' I can use VFP 9.0. I'm talking about the language FP 3.0. That's why i talked about xHarbour and dBase. I don't like the .NET framework so, I'm looking for another language or platform.

Comment: I don't know that many people who are still wanting to stay with the old xBase stuff.  xHarbour and dBase are all based on technology that is about 30 years old now.

If you don't like .NET (and a lot don't) Have you looked into Java?  IMO you're going to have to look into one or another of those if you're going to be writing apps that are deploy-able on more than a desktop.

Comment: Well, the C Language has 40 years now and it's still one of the most used programming languages, but anyway, I'll keep waiting until Microsoft release the FoxPro code... maybe someday in the future... maybe. Thank's for your answer.

Comment: Yes, the age of a language is irrelevant. Syntactically Visual FoxPro is extremely well suited to working with data in an OOP fashion. What is dated is the DBF format and the locking mechanism associated with it. But you can just use the backend of your choice via ODBC/OLEDB

Answer (score 0):

Alpha5 V11 has some similarities to VFP.
I am also looking for something like a VFP replacement and so far I only see lianja and maybe embarcadero as possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is quite the equivalent to VFP but I did see a product called Suneido which appears to be a similar product to MS Access and or VFP. I have not tried to use this but if anyone has it might be good to hear about.
http://www.suneido.com/